# How does Reflexive association work in SAILS JS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sails.js

Here is my User model: I am trying to create a reflexive association among users. Mentors and mentees

```
fullName: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  description: 'Full representation of the user\'s name',
  maxLength: 120,
  example: 'Lisa Microwave van der Jenny'
},

typeOfUser: {
  required: true,
  type: 'string',
  example: 'mentor',
  description: 'The user\'s type of account.',
},
skills:{
  collection:'skills',
  via: 'userId'
},

mentees:{
  collection: 'user',
  via: 'mentors'
},
mentors:{
  collection:'user',
  via: 'mentees'
}
```

Here is my code.

```
// Add mentor of mentorId as the mentor of currentUser
await User.addToCollection(3, 'mentor',8);

// Find mentor and populate mentees 
var showMentee = await User.findOne(8).populate('mentee');
```

The Response is correct:

```
{
    "mentee": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "fullName": "1234",
            "typeOfUser": "mentee"
        }
    ],
    "id": 8,
    "fullName": "1234",
    "typeOfUser": "mentor"
}
```

But the problem is with the association table that sails has created:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id | user_mentee | user_mentor |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |           8 |           3 |
|  2 |           8 |           3 |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

I can not understand the column naming in this case. The mentor id is 8 and mentee id is 3, but it is showing opposite.